# is this graph of loss function or input data distribution?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, optimization, loss-functions, convex

I have been looking at the Batch normalization and got confused.
[image]

https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+draw+non+convex+optimization+loss+function+in+graph&newwindow=1&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=p9jTQ-nE7iJyfM%252CVwHlY7V21gHQFM%252C_&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kQQK_-BeVyvG8Co4iKdUS4oB9rzxQ&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjApZaGjIbrAhVkFqYKHf-aCUAQ9QEwAnoECAoQBQ&biw=2077&bih=1065#imgrc=En2uJKnp9l7i7M

I saw the this kind of non convex or convex graph when you learning the deep learning.
then

```
1. is this graph of loss function? 
2.How they graph this because we do not know the entire loss function graph. 
3. is normalizing change the graph of loss function? 
4. for batch normalization. is it same thing as normalizing the input data. between deep learning layers? then it also change the loss function graph?
```

Comment: I see that you have four questions. This site works best when you ask one question at a time. Perhaps you could edit your post to focus on the question that's giving you the most trouble, and we can help you get unstuck from there. Additionally, we have a number of questions about neural networks and loss functions. Perhaps you'd find some helpful posts by using the search; for starters, https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bneural-networks%5D+loss+

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.04829) appears to be the original source.

1. In the context of the paper -- yes.
2. We almost always do know the precise loss function for any given model. The typical problem is that the loss function is in a several million/billion dimensional space, which is makes it difficult for visualization. There are techniques to get around this -- see [Visualizing the Loss Landscape of Neural Nets](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/7875-visualizing-the-loss-landscape-of-neural-nets.pdf) -- but that's not to say that's how this particular figure was created